# How do I find the remaining items in a vector after sampling?

Tags: r, vector, random

I created a vector as below

```
Expenditure
 [1] 13.9 15.4 15.8 17.9 18.3 19.9 20.6 21.4 21.7 23.1
[11] 20.0 20.6 24.0 25.1 26.2 30.0 30.6 30.9 33.8 44.1
```

Now I picked 10 random samples from `Expenditure`

```
ransomsample <- sample(Expenditure,10)
ransomsample
 [1] 19.9 21.4 20.0 30.0 17.9 25.1
 [7] 26.2 21.7 33.8 13.9
```

Now I want to find the remaining items in `Expenditure` after I created the sample called `ransomsample`. Any existing function that I can use?

Comment: any attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: Have a look at `help("%in%")`

Comment: Eventuall you can do the sampling by construkting a logical index vector `i <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), length(Expenditure), repl=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
#generate 20 random numbers
x <- rnorm(20)
#sample 10 of them
randomSample <- sample(x, 10, replace = FALSE)

#we can get the ones we sampled with:
x[x %in% randomSample]

#Let's confirm this. NOTE - added sort() to easily see they do match
cbind(sort(randomSample), sort(x[x %in% randomSample]))

#So we want to negate the above
x[!(x %in% randomSample)]
```

Comment: Note that this may not give the desired behaviour if there are duplicates in the data.  This works for the example in OP which has no duplicates, but caution is needed to use this approach on data with duplicated values.  This approach will remove all values in x that match values in the sample, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The way to approach this depends on how you need to deal with replicates in the vector from which you sample.  If you can be certain there are no duplicates, then the simple approach given by @Chase using `x[!(x %in% randomSample)]` is perfect.  **But**, if there are potentially duplicates, then more care is needed.  We can see this clearly in the following:

```
# Start with a vector (length=9) replete with replicates
x <- rep(letters[1:3],3)

# Now sample 8 of its 9 values (leaving one unsampled)
set.seed(123)
randomSample <- sample(x, 8, replace = FALSE)

# try using simple method to find which value remains after sampling
x[!(x %in% randomSample)]
## character(0)
```

This simple approach fails because `%in%` matches *all* occurrences of the sampled values within x.  If this is what you want then this is the method for you.  But, if you want to know how many of each value remains after sampling then we need to take another line.

There are several ways, but probably the most elegant is to subtract the frequency table of the sample from the frequency table of initial vector, to provide a table of the remaining unsampled values.  Then generate a vector of the unsampled values from this table.

```
xtab <- as.data.frame(table(x))
stab <- as.data.frame(table(randomSample))
xtab[which(xtab$x %in% stab$randomSample),]$Freq <- 
  xtab[which(xtab$x %in% stab$randomSample),]$Freq - stab$Freq
rep(xtab$x, xtab$Freq)
## [1] a
```